# Helm stuck on "another operation is in progress" but no other releases or installs exist

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I know title sounds like "did you even try to google", but helm gives me the typical: `another operation (install/upgrade/rollback) is in progress`

What I can't figure out, is there's no actual releases anywhere that are actually in progress.

I've run `helm list --all --all-namespaces` and the list is just blank.  Same with running `helm history` against any namespace I can think of.  Nothing, all just blank.  I've even deleted the namespace and everything in it that the app was initially installed in, and it still is broken.

I've also found answers to delete secrets, which I have, and it doesn't help.

Is there some way to hard reset helm's state? Because all the  answers I find on this topic involve rolling back, uninstalling, or deleting stuck releases, and none exist on this entire cluster.

Helm is v3.8.1 if that helps.  Thanks for any help on this, it's driving me crazy.

Comment: I have had a similar issue, for me `helm list -a` did work and showed me the failed release. This is similar to `helm list --all` 

`--all or -a`: show all releases without any filter applied.

I see that you have tried `helm list --all --all-namespaces` but can you  try without `--all-namespaces` and check once.

Comment: @ishuar thanks for the reply. I did try all sorts of permutations of that command, including `--all` and `--all-namespaces` on their won as well as combined.  And it didn't work :(.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out.  The pipeline running helm executed from a gitlab runner that runs on one cluster, but uses a kubernetes context to target my desired cluster.  At some point, the kubernetes context wasn't loaded correctly, and a bad install went to the host cluster the runner lived on.

While I was still targeting a different cluster, the helm command saw a bad install on the cluster local to it, so a `helm list --all` didn't see anything on the target clusetr.